# How to create IBuffer from HBITMAP in C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, c++-cx

I have code, that making screenshot, and saving it to HBITMAP

```
GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(NULL);
HDC hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);
int width = rc.right - rc.left;
int height = rc.bottom - rc.top;
HBITMAP hbmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen,width, height);
SelectObject(hdc, hbmp);
PrintWindow(hwnd, hdc, PW_CLIENTONLY);
```

Then, i want to create new **Buffer** (windows.storage.streams.buffer) class instance from my **hbmp** object

```
Buffer obj = new Buffer(hbmp); // HOW TO DO SOMETHING LIKE THIS ???
SoftwareBitmap^ softwareBitmap = SoftwareBitmap::CreateCopyFromBuffer(obj ,
BitmapPixelFormat::Bgra8, width, height);
```

The main goal - save screenshot of window to SoftwareBitmap object

Comment: That's not C++. Could be C++/CX, but you also tagged this question using [tag:winforms], so that cannot be it. Please use the correct tags.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144904(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=winrt+screenshot

Comment: It's possible to use C++/CX and Windows Runtime types in a non-UWP project, but this seems suspicious... if you're trying to mix `HWND`s and `HDC`s with UWP, you will hit lots of roadblocks. They're not supported together.